# How to handle user permissions in a database schema?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm currently creating a database model for a system containing users, which can have permissions to some categories. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
User
- username
- password

Category
- name
```

I now want to give users permissions to some categories, but not to others. So I thought of doing this like so:

```
User
- username
- password

Category
- name

Permission
- ForeignKeyField(username)
- ForeignKeyField(Category)
```

My question: is this a logical way or are there better or more usual ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I see missing are ID's. I would have my Schema set up as such:

```
User
- ID
- Username
- Password

Category
- ID
- Name

Permission
- ID
- UserID
- CategoryID
```

Comment: Yeah I know. I thought I'dd just omit them for clarity (and I use an orm). But for the rest, the saving of permissions in a separate table is a normal and good way to do this?

Comment: yes, it is. That way you could also restrict the database so not everyone can edit or see the permissions table, if you wanted to.

Comment: Yes, I have done dozens of projects that require different User Permissions and this is exactly how I handle it.

Comment: I would like to help the person who down voted this answer. Let me know if there is any way I can help you.

Comment: I didn't down-vote this before, but I am doing so now.  You may have done this dozens of times, that does not make it right.  OP is not visiting SO, so I won't bother with a full answer.  (a) This breaks 2NF (b) The correct answer: create a Role or GroupUser table, with permissions therein, set once, and an Associative table to User based on that.  The principle is to group objects at the highest level, not the lowest, as you have done.  Good for tiny databases and users who love changing one fact in a thousand locations.

Comment: I see the issue, and this was used for small projects. However we now use ASP Identity which handles this all. Thank you for your feedback! It is humbling to see the stupid mistakes we make over the years